# jenkins sonarqube scanner exits with non-zero code 1 error

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line number must be strictly positive: 0

SonarScanner 4.3.0.2102
cobertura-maven-plugin - 2.7
We are trying to run the build via Jenkins. But the build is getting failure with below error. Please assist on this.

```
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Line number must be strictly positive: 0
at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:197)
at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.coverage.internal.DefaultCoverage.validateLine(DefaultCoverage.java:94)
at org.sonar.api.batch.sensor.coverage.internal.DefaultCoverage.lineHits(DefaultCoverage.java:81)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaReportParser.collectFileData(CoberturaReportParser.java:117)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaReportParser.collectFileMeasures(CoberturaReportParser.java:98)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaReportParser.collectPackageMeasures(CoberturaReportParser.java:87)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaReportParser.parse(CoberturaReportParser.java:67)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaReportParser.parseReport(CoberturaReportParser.java:58)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaSensor.parseReport(CoberturaSensor.java:72)
at org.sonar.plugins.cobertura.CoberturaSensor.execute(CoberturaSensor.java:66)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.AbstractSensorWrapper.analyse(AbstractSensorWrapper.java:48)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:85)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.lambda$execute$1(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.withModuleStrategy(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:77)
at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.ModuleSensorsExecutor.execute(ModuleSensorsExecutor.java:59)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:82)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:400)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:395)
at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:358)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.doAfterStart(GlobalContainer.java:141)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:136)
at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:122)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.doExecute(Batch.java:73)
at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:99)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
ERROR:
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
WARN: Unable to locate ‘report-task.txt’ in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succeed?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: Hi @Malinda, please post on https://community.sonarsource.com/ to get better response, StackOverflow isn't the best place for SonarQube questions

Comment: Problem looks like it can be resolve this way: https://github.com/Idean/sonar-swift/issues/257#issuecomment-613142975 (says sonar-swift but you can find a similar resolution)